# Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame reference index value in column calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to efficiently use values from a DataFrame's MultiIndex in some calculations.  For example, starting with:

```
np.random.seed(456)
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in random.sample(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=50, freq='W').tolist(), 5)]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
df['SmallestNum'] = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('Name')['Num'].transform('min').values
```

Suppose I want to calculate a new column `Diff = Num - SmallestNum`.  An efficient but, I assume, kludgy way is to copy the Index level I want to reference into a bona fide column and then do the difference:

```
df['NumCol'] = df.index.get_level_values(1)
df['Diff'] = df['NumCol'] - df['SmallestNum']
```

But I feel like I'm still not understanding the proper way to work with DataFrames if I'm doing this.  I thought the "correct" solution would look like either of the following, which don't create and store a full copy of the index values:

```
df['Diff'] = df.transform(lambda x: x.index.get_level_values(1) - x['SmallestNum'])
df['Diff'] = df.reset_index(level=1).apply(lambda x: x['Num'] - x['SmallestNum'])
```

... however not only do neither of these expressions work*, but also my understanding is that DataFrame operations like `.transform` or `.apply` are bound to be significantly slower than ones that operate on explicit "vectorized" row references.

So what is the "correct and efficient" way to write the calculation for the new `Diff` column in this example?

---

<sup>*</sup> Update: This problem was compounded by the fact (possibly bug) that the index level 1 values were not unique, which causes formulas that work when the index values are unique to fail with `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`.  Fortunately [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48977949/2662901) contains workarounds that appear to be as efficient as explicitly vectorized calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need simply subtract:

```
df['Diff'] = df.index.get_level_values(1) - df['SmallestNum']
print (df)

              Vals  SmallestNum  Diff
Name Num                             
A    28   1.180140           28     0
     44   0.984257           28    16
     90   1.835646           28    62
     43  -1.886823           28    15
     29   0.424763           28     1
B    80  -0.433105           38    42
     61  -0.166838           38    23
     46   0.754634           38     8
     38   1.966975           38     0
     93   0.200671           38    55
C    40   0.742752           12    28
     82  -1.264271           12    70
     12  -0.112787           12     0
     78   0.667358           12    66
     70   0.357900           12    58
```

EDIT: for non unique `DatetimeIndex` in second level working subtract numpy arrays created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
np.random.seed(456)
a = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=6).values
j = [['A'] * 5 + ['B'] * 5 + ['C'] * 5, pd.to_datetime(np.random.choice(a, size=15))]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
df['SmallestNum'] = df.reset_index(level=1).groupby('Name')['Num'].transform('min').values
df['Diff'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).values - df['SmallestNum'].values
print (df)
                     Vals SmallestNum   Diff
Name Num                                    
A    2015-01-04 -1.842419  2015-01-02 2 days
     2015-01-06 -0.786788  2015-01-02 4 days
     2015-01-04  1.180140  2015-01-02 2 days
     2015-01-02  0.984257  2015-01-02 0 days
     2015-01-03  1.835646  2015-01-02 1 days
B    2015-01-05 -1.886823  2015-01-03 2 days
     2015-01-03  0.424763  2015-01-03 0 days
     2015-01-05 -0.433105  2015-01-03 2 days
     2015-01-06 -0.166838  2015-01-03 3 days
     2015-01-05  0.754634  2015-01-03 2 days
C    2015-01-06  1.966975  2015-01-02 4 days
     2015-01-06  0.200671  2015-01-02 4 days
     2015-01-05  0.742752  2015-01-02 3 days
     2015-01-02 -1.264271  2015-01-02 0 days
     2015-01-04 -0.112787  2015-01-02 2 days
```

Another solution:

```
df['Diff'] = (df.reset_index(level=1)
                .groupby('Name')['Num']
                .transform(lambda x: x - x.min())
                .values)
print (df)
                     Vals   Diff
Name Num                        
A    2015-01-04 -1.842419 2 days
     2015-01-06 -0.786788 4 days
     2015-01-04  1.180140 2 days
     2015-01-02  0.984257 0 days
     2015-01-03  1.835646 1 days
B    2015-01-05 -1.886823 2 days
     2015-01-03  0.424763 0 days
     2015-01-05 -0.433105 2 days
     2015-01-06 -0.166838 3 days
     2015-01-05  0.754634 2 days
C    2015-01-06  1.966975 4 days
     2015-01-06  0.200671 4 days
     2015-01-05  0.742752 3 days
     2015-01-02 -1.264271 0 days
     2015-01-04 -0.112787 2 days
```

Comment: That works on the example in the OP, but it's failing on a bigger test case where the index level 1 is of type `datetime64` with `NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented`.  Let me see if I can generate a test case showing that....

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to work with time indices.  I'm updating my example with the following, which causes what you show here to break: `j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in random.sample(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=50, freq='W').tolist(), 5)]`

Comment: I simulate it, there are duplicated datetimes. Please give me some time.

Comment: It seems as bug, but if convert to numpy array it working.

Comment: Ah ha: I see that in my example.  So it gets trickier when the index level has non-unique values!  I eagerly await your insight!

Comment: Ya, in my opinion it is bug, but there are 2 possible solutions - subtract numpy arrays or use transform. Please check edited answer.

Comment: Agreed: Fortunately both of the solutions you provide appear to be as fast as my "kludgy" but obviously vectorized solution (which mucks up the DataFrame with an unnecessary column).  Thanks!